# How to Reconcile Pax Arcanum and Permission of New Second Awakenings?

Tags: lore, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Archmasters possess superhuman capabilities of both foresight and scheming, have immense supernatural powers, and are always on the lookout for aspirants. The Pax Arcanum forbids interfering with another's claimed interests, and forbids claiming a new interest in a way that would interfere with another's already-claimed interests.

Given the degree to which everything is interconnected, it is no exaggeration to say that any aspirant succeeding at Threshold Seeking *will* interfere with many of the existing Archmasters' claimed interests, more likely sooner rather than later, and many Archmasters know it long in advance.

**If so, how come old Archmasters do not prevent such interference by preventing Second Awakenings?**

The only thing capable of protecting an aspirant seems to be an interest claim by an existing Archmaster . . . but making such a claim seems to be a breach of the Pax Arcanum based on the reasoning above. Is there a way to reconcile all of the above observations, or do I have a flaw in my reasoning or understanding somewhere?

(I'm researching *Imperial Mysteries* specifically as an inspiration for certain aspects of worldbuilding; my overall knowledge of Chronicles of Darkness is rather spotty, so I suspect that there's a good chance that I'm just missing or misunderstanding something of the above.)

Comment: 1st or 2nd edition Mage the Awakening? I'm not sure if the answer would matter, but it might.

Comment: @VLAZ AFAIK there is only one edition of Imperial Mysteries, so the *default* is 1e, but I wouldn't want to shoo away 2e people and their answers. I have no idea whether anything in 2e provides better/smoother reconciliation, but if it does, those answers would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if it matters, to be honest - I'll have to double check but I think MtAw 2nd edition makes mages a lot more *focused* on chasing after mysteries and those would be quite esoteric and of very personal interest to each individual. So, archmages would be consumed with their stuff. Essentially, all mages turn into uber-nerds that specialist in some very obscure things - while humans would have trekkies, a mage might focus on the pattern of blinking lights throughout episodes, an archmage would pursue a PhD in a distant 10 year stretch of history of the beards of Vulcans.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah, so 2e Archmages aren't these vast broad intellects, but more like idiot savants. Thanks for the info. That may in fact change the premise and not just the reconciliation. Adding 1e tag.

Comment: Yeah. I've only read 2e once but there was a very big emphasis on mages pursuing very esoteric pieces of knowledge. Each would be compelled to do so and the more advanced the mage, the more obscure and esoteric the knowledge they crave would be.